# How to expand Accordion and the page scroll down accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

I use an customised Accordion for our React application. 
There is one problem when I located an Accordion on the bottom of page.

When a user click the accordion to open, the page does not scroll down to the expanded area inside the accordion. So most likely a user cannot know if there is the expanded area in the below.

My question is that how can we add a functionality that the page scroll down as the accordion expand?

A part of the code looks like this:

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
 render () {
 return <section className='dashboard'>
     <div className='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4'>
     <!—omitted some codes here—>
     {!this.props.isNotEmpty && <HeaderAccordion>
         <Content />
     </HeaderAccordion>
     }
   </div>

 </section>
 }
}
```

Comment: It is most likely related to your CSS and not react, the container of the Accordion must have overflow: hidden or something like that

Comment: can you provide an example of the issue working in codepen or similar

Comment: did you find a solution?